# Flutter didUpdateWidget concept

Tags: flutter

I went through the questions/answers related to didUpdateWidget,but can't still understand the didUpdateWidget lifecycle method !, i'd be appreciate it if somebody can explain it in simple way and that why we need to utilize it.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about it?

Comment: i don't understand when to use it and what's it's equivalent in react native or kotlin?